# Estimate Dictionary size using Zipf’s Law

Tags: information-retrieval, estimation

How would one go about Calculating the Dictionary Size(no.of unique words) of a collection using Zipfs Law?

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary size is approximated by Heap's Law and not directly by Zipf's law.

Unique words = constant1 x (Total. words)^costant2 where constant1 is usually between 10 and 100 and constant2 is usually between 0.5 and 0.6.